# Use DirectSound3D effects again on Windows Vista and above

Tags: windows, audio

In version prior to vista, they were an API called Directsound which allowed to access sound devices directly.
On top of that API, exist DirectSound3D which allowed to perform spatial sound effect from stereo speakers *(for example making feel a noise or a voice come from behind you)*

Since Windows vista, Microsoft put efforts to enhance the sound driver model, making impossible to control the sound device from userspace directly.

In order to solve compatibility problems, Microsoft added an emulation layer for directsound.dll *(the dll which implement the directsound api)*.
However, that layer doesn’t really enable the DirectSound3D api. Attempts to use DirectSound3D will result in every sound being played in mono speaker mode *(so all spatial effects are lost)*.

So is a there a software or a virtual driver to restore full DirectSound3D functionalities ?
I took a look at IndirectSound, however, it’s for 32 bits Windows only and it doesn’t support eax.

Comment: More details [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/21651). Note that most games are shipped as a large set of binary blobs.

Comment: Was DirectSound3D an API (library that games/etc can use)? If yes, are you looking for something that implements the same API?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul : This was mainly used by games. But other programs like kkriegers also befefited from it. Again that api is already implemented by Microsoft on vista and up, the problem is the vista’s compatibility layer remove all spatial effects *(so sounds still play but are reduced to mono speaker)*.